# Jquery radio button after page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, radio-button, page-refresh

I have a form where, if a radio button is selected, the user is prompted with an additional text field. I'm using the following jQuery to accomplish this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio[name="accountType"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'typeA'){
            //show the hidden layer
            $( "#additionalQuestion" ).show("slow");
           }
        if ($(this).val() == 'typeB'){
            //show the hidden layer
            $( "#additionalQuestion" ).hide("slow");
           }
    });
});
```

Everything works perfectly unless the user's responses fail my PHP form validation, in which case the form is redisplayed (with the user's responses injected via PHP).  At this point, the #additionalQuestion layer is no longer visible, even though the appropriate radio button is selected. How can I ensure that the #additionalQuestion layer remains visible in this case?

Comment: Along with showing/hiding the layer on "change", you could check for the radio button value on document "load" and show or hide based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same place you're injecting form elements, inject a JavaScript variable that your `$(document).ready()` can pick up

In PHP

```
if ($form_failed)
    echo '<script>var showAdditionalQuestion = 1;</script>';
```

Then in JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (showAdditionalQuestion)
        $('#showAdditionalQuestion').show();
});
```

(Or just inject the code so show the section directly)

This is probably more flexible and robust than just checking if the checkbox is checked on load (what if a form input is set but you don't want to show that section on load?), but that's an alternative

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly and was very easy to add to my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this inside doc.ready:

```
if ($('input:radio[name="accountType"]').val() == 'typeA') {
  $( "#additionalQuestion" ).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Poornima mentioned in a comment, you can run the check both when the radio button is selected and when the page loads.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function checkForAdditionalQuestion() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'typeA'){
            //show the hidden layer
            $( "#additionalQuestion" ).show("slow");
        }
        if ($(this).val() == 'typeB'){
            //show the hidden layer
            $( "#additionalQuestion" ).hide("slow");
        }
    }

    checkForAdditionalQuestion();

    $('input:radio[name="accountType"]').change(function() {
        checkForAdditionalQuestion();
    });
});
```